# How to show a spinner while the search is going on in react js?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to make a Spinner that will show when the search is going on and hide when the search results are shown in the page. What is the correct way of doing it? This is my code:

```
const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false);

function search (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsSearching(true);
    setSearchValue(e.target.value);
    setSearchString(e.target.value);
    setIsSearching(false);
    if (e.target.value === "") {
        reset();
    }
}

<Input onChange={e => search(e)} value={searchValue} />

<Spinner style={{ display: isSearching ? 'block': 'none' }} />
```

Comment: Do you have some API fetching going on? Or just want to show spinning when the user is typing?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false);

function search (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsSearching(true);
    setSearchValue(e.target.value);
    setSearchString(e.target.value);
    setIsSearching(false);
    if (e.target.value === "") {
        reset();
    }
}

return isSearching ? (
    <Spinner style={{ display: isSearching ? 'block': 'none' }} />
) : (
    <Input onChange={e => search(e)} value={searchValue} />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show the Spinner component while you are searching.

```
{ isSearching ? <Spinner /> : null }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with this. Let's See what you need to do:

1. Create two states, 1 to hold the search result and 2. to detect loading.

```
const [searchResult, setSearch] = useState("")
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)
```

Now, in your JSX, create a condition, such that if the content is loading, show the spinner, else show the result:

```
<div>
   { isLoading? <Spinner />:<div>{{ searchResult }}</div> }
</div>
```

then, in your search handler, which will be asynchronous:

```
async function search(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   setLoading(true)
   //fetch the data and parse it
     .then(data => { setSearch(data); setLoading(false) })
}
```

And that's it